# Removing the "pm-software" tag as an uninformative superset

Tags: discussion, tags, community-review, call-to-action

### The "PM-Software" Tag is Too Generic, and Needs Clean-Up and Removal

#### The Problem

I'd like to remove the [pm-software](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pm-software) tag, but we currently have 189 questions already tagged with it. This is something that would require some community involvement to re-categorize and clean up properly.

Basically, we discourage use of generic or superset tags whenever possible. This particular tag often leads to "shopping questions" or elicits questions that belong on [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) instead. I'd like to see us get rid of this tag altogether in favor of PM-specific tool tags.

#### Recommended Actions

I'd like to recommend the following. If you have privileges, please look at all questions with the [pm-software](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pm-software) tag, and:

1. Delete the tag if the question already has a more specific tool tag associated with it.
2. Delete the tag if the question also has the [software-development](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-development) tag associated with it, as the question is presumably about managing a software development project.
3. Flag the question for closure or deletion if it is a shopping or polling question and is too old to migrate.
4. Add tool-specific tags if the question would otherwise be on-topic, but needs a more specific tag (e.g. [ms-project](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ms-project) or [jira](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jira).
5. Bring up any unusual cases for discussion.

I don't want to see any questions orphaned as a result of this clean-up, which is why I think a manual review is in order. Mass deletion of the tag could result in questions that lack a meaningful tag, and that's something we should definitely try to avoid!